# Check if pandas query is neither empty nor NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running a query in a dataframe to retrieve a column value whenever a condition is met. For instance, I want to get `col1` whenever `col2=0`.

```py
result = df['col1'].loc[df['col2']==0]
```

Next, I want to check that

1. The results are not empty, i.e. there is at least one instance where `col2=0`
2. The returned value of `col1` is not NaN

So I write:

```py
if not result.empty and not result.isnull():
  pass
```

But this raises:

```py
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am I actually supposed to do?

Comment: All non-NaN or just one non-NaN ?

Comment: `.isnull()` returns a Boolean array of the entire dataframe `True` or `False`. Will it be `None` if `all` or if `any`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: @azro, let's assume that we want all non-NaN. In practice, for my real-life case, the query will always return one row, as `col2` contains only unique values. @Trenton, I'm sure that's it, but I'm struggling to apply it to my case.

Comment: It seems like only `if not result.empty:` is required. Otherwise `if not result.empty and not all(result.isnull()):`